# Sheaves of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Learning about sheaves it was said that one can define sheaves with values in an arbitrary category, so for me it is „natural“ to ask wether one could take as the category „sheaves of abelian groups“. Does this lead to any useful notions and if so, what about „sheaves of sheaves of sheaves ... of sheaves of abelian groups“? Thanks!

Comment: Let $\Delta$ be the category whose objects are the posets $[n]=\{0<1 \cdots <n\}$ and whose morphisms are the order preserving functions. Then set valued presheaves on the category $\Delta$ are called simplicial sets which form an interesting/important category of objects. Often one will see presheaves with values in simplicial sets, is that kind of example what you want?

Comment: @user45878 I’ll take a look at it and hopefully learn something; I already did so noticing that presheaves are more generally defined than I knew from my basic classes. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Also I believe you have a well-defined functor $Sh(X\times Y)\to Sh(X,Sh(Y))$ such that a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X\times Y$ is mapped to $U\mapsto(V\mapsto\mathcal{F}(U\times V))$. I haven't tried to prove anything about it but is this a direction you are interested in ?

Comment: The notion of what it means to have ''sheaves of whatever category you want'' is an important one that leads to descent theory. This question gets subtle, complicated, and very interesting when you try to do things like have ''sheaves of categories'' (so sheaves $F:\mathscr{C}^{op} \to \mathbf{Cat}$ for a category $\mathscr{C}$). Vistoli has some notes on this that are a good read.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers! Looks as though there‘s a lot of interesting stuff out there.